# PHP link not appearing

Tags: php, html, echo

I am trying to have the text "Facebook" to be a clickable link but for some reason it will not appear on the front-end.

**Snippet of Code:**

```
function friend_contact() {

$healthcard = get_field('healthcard');
$facebook = get_field('facebook');
$phone = get_field('phone');
$fax   = get_field('fax');
$email = get_field('email');

$post_info = '';

if (isset($healthcard['url'])) {
    $img = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/images/mail-icon.png";
    $post_info .= '<a class="healthcard" href="'.$healthcard['url'].'"><img src="'.$img.'" /> Download Contact</a>';
}

if (isset($facebook['url']) && isset($healthcard['url']) {
    $post_info .= ' | ';
}   

if (isset($facebook['url'])) {
$post_info .= '<a href="'.$facebook['url'].'"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:blue"></i> Facebook</a>';
}


$post_info .= '<ul class="friend-contact">';
$post_info .= "<li>$email</li>";
$post_info .= "<li>p: $phone</li>";
$post_info .= "<li>f: $fax</li>";
$post_info .= "</ul>";

var_dump($facebook);    
var_dump(get_field('facebook'));

genesis_markup( array(
    'html5' => sprintf( '<div class="entry-meta">%s</div>', $post_info ),
    'xhtml' => sprintf( '<div class="post-info">%s</div>', $post_info ),
) );
}
```

**Results of Dump:**

```
string(21) "https://www.yahoo.com" string(21) "https://www.yahoo.com"
```

---

[image]

Alternative Code With `['url']`:

```
if (isset($facebook) && isset($healthcard['url']) {
    $post_info .= ' | ';
}

if (isset($facebook)) {
    $post_info .= '<a class="facebook" a href="$facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>';
    }
```

I think the root of the problem is with the code bit, `['url']`
Thank you in advance

Comment: what does `get_field` return?

Comment: You are outputting `$post_info` right?

Comment: `echo $post_info .= '<a href="'.$facebook['url'].'">...`? if there's no loop, remove the dot/concatenate too. `$post_info = '<a...`

Comment: check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *Talk amongst yourselves...*, I'm getting me a cappuccino, *ciao*

Comment: Yes I am outputting $post_info @chris85

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: you have this in comments `$post_info .= '<a href="'.$linkedin['url'].'">` but something entirely different in your code; *which one is it?*

Comment: and as stated already, what does `get_field()` do/return? your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry @Fred-ii- I updated the code now. Please let me know if u need more info.

Comment: `get_field()` that function is still not in the code. I don't know if that's a core function of any CMS, so I'll have to pass on the question. Gotta run, good luck. Cheers

Comment: Dang it, but `get_field()` is a function from ACF, http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Check the value of facebook['url'] . The anchor will not be clickable unless there is some value for 'href'.

Comment: @aakashbhowmick I believe I am checking value of `facebook['url'] with the two dumps I have at the end. Added results to question above ^

Comment: Can you provide dump for 'post_info' as well?

Comment: @aakashbhowmick added dump for `post_info` and the other two fields bio and card both are producing urls but sadly facebook is just pointing to `$facebook`

Comment: From your `var_dump($facebook)` it appears `$facebook` is just the string  `"https://www.yahoo.com"` rather than an array structure that would have a `['url']` key. So you should just be checking and using `$facebook` directly, rather than `$facebook['url']` in a few places ??  I suspect the same situation for `$healthcard`

Comment: I had tried that before as well @MichaelBerkowski without ['url'] but the problem remains either way ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You echo your string with single quotes, thus it won't process the variable. That looks like it's between double quotes, but that is part of your string. So either make it

```
$post_info .= '<a class="facebook" href="'.$facebook.'"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>';
```

or reverse the quotes.

```
$post_info .= "<a class='facebook' href='$facebook'><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i> Facebook</a>";
```

Edit: as to what's the better way, is another discussion. As long as you're consistent.

Comment: Last thing, how can I show the url so users and either copy the full url or just click the link?

Comment: They can click the link now right? Or what exactly do you mean? if you want to show the link, then put another '.$facebook.' between </i> and </a>, but not sure if that is what you mean. :). Didn't see, but there's an extra "a" in the <a...> you can remove that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you missed a closing parenthesis in the following line:

> if (isset($facebook['url']) && isset($healthcard['url']) {

Your code should look like this:

```
if ( isset($facebook['url']) && isset($healthcard['url']) ) {
```

Also the `$facebook` variable is a string so `$facebook['url']` is not valid and `isset($facebook['url'])` returns always **false**. So replace everything with $facebook without the brackets part.

If `$healthcard` is also a string and not an array then you should also replace `$healthcard['url']` with `$healthcard`.

Comment: I wish that was the solution but sadly that does not effect the end result. For the link stay points to the variable name `$facebook` instead of its value `www.yahoo.com`

Comment: So just this `if ( isset($facebook) && isset($healthcard['url']) ) {`

Comment: If yes ^ I already tried that before and same result. Clicking the link will take me to `site.url + /$facebook` Also `healthcard` is an array so `['url']` is correct for that field.